# SAS: Why does %include not print comments from the included program in the log?

Tags: logging, sas, include, comments

I'm running a lot of smaller SAS programs for a main.sas using %include. I would like for the comments in all the smaller programs to be printed to the log exactly as they would be had I run each program individually. I can't seem to find an option to help me (something like mprint just for included programs). I'm new to SAS, and this might be a very simple problem, but I'm really going nuts over it. And now we are talking about it, can anyone help me with a little insight about the differences between input and source? I find it very difficult to get help from the SAS help-pages.

Thank you so much!
Kira

Comment: Your second question isn't clear.  In the context of %include, the "input file" and the "source file" might refer to the same thing (i.e. the file that is being read by the %include statement).  Or it's possible "source" file refers to the main fail that contains the %include statement.  Can you give more context (quote the docs or whatever) to where you are seeing these terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.  Just add `option source2;` at the start of your main program.  This tells SAS to print the code and comments to the log of all programs run with `%include`.

Comment: I knew it had to be simple! I guess my biggest problem with SAS is not understanding the jargon of the SAS help pages. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The `SOURCE` and `SOURCE2` options control whether the SAS code is included in the log. These normally default to `SOURCE` and `NOSOURCE2`. You can change the SOURCE2 system option, or add the `/source2` option to the `%INCLUDE` statement. Use this little program to generate a couple of sample files with SAS code.

```
filename file1 temp ;
filename file2 temp ;
data _null_;
  file file1 ;
  put '* This line is from FILE1;';
  file file2 ;
  put '* This line is from FILE2;';
run;
```

Now use `%INCLUDE` with and without the SOURCE2 option.

```
%include file1 file2 ;
%include file1 file2 / source2 ;
```

Here is how the log will look.

```
 71         %include file1 file2 ;
 74         %include file1 file2 / source2 ;
 NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) file FILE1 is file /tmp/SAS_workAEE90000185C_localhost.localdomain/#LN00050.
 75        +* This line is from FILE1;
 NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) ending.
 NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) file FILE2 is file /tmp/SAS_workAEE90000185C_localhost.localdomain/#LN00051.
 76        +* This line is from FILE2;
 NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) ending.
 77
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer in detail :-)